# How to reduce dimension of a tensor with keeping specific indexed elements of that dimension?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensor

The reduce of dimension is similar to what reduce_max() does, the difference is I want a specific index of the element in that dimension instead of simply picking the maximal one. For example, I have a 2x3 tensor A = [[0,1,2],[2,2,0]]. If I apply tf.argmax(A), I get index tensor [1, 1, 0]. How can I use this index tensor [1, 1, 0] to get the tensor as tf.reduce_max(A, 0) = [2, 2, 2]?

The reason I am not using tf.reduce_max directly is I want to use different index tensor instead of the argmax index tensor to reduce the dimension or keep the indexed value instead of the maximal value at that dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tf.gather_nd` function to do that but you will need to convert that `[1, 1, 0]` index tensor into 2D tensor.

Here I assume that the index tensor is a numpy array (you can convert tensorflow tensor into numpy array by calling `.numpy()` method.

```
idx = np.array([1, 1, 0])

idx = np.c_[idx[:, np.newaxis], np.arange(len(idx))]

print(idx)

# Output:
# array([[1, 0],
#        [1, 1],
#        [0, 2]])
```

Which means: pick (row1, col0), (row1, col1), and (row0, col2) when using the above mentioned `tf.gather_nd`

```
A = tf.Variable([[0, 1, 2], [2, 2, 0]])

tf.gather_nd(A, idx)
```

Will give you the expected `[2, 2, 2]` tensor.